# Q.Apache Flink : how to get current key during initializeState

Tags: apache-flink

i want to init value state from my own db(es.eg) if the application can not restore state from the backend , but how can i get current key during initializeState ?

here is the sample code :

```
@Override
public void initializeState(FunctionInitializationContext context) throws Exception {
    KeyedStateStore stateStore = context.getKeyedStateStore();
    ValueStateDescriptor<PickUpState> pickUpStateConfig = new ValueStateDescriptor<>("pickUpState", PickUpState.class);

    ValueState<PickUpState> state = stateStore.getState(pickUpStateConfig);
    pickUpState = state;
    if(!context.isRestored()){
        //get the current key helpful
        String key =  ...

        PickUpState upState = initStateFromEs(key);
        state.update(upState);

    }
}
```

Any repply will be helpful , thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible because there is no current key when `initializeState` is called.

Each instance of a user function is multiplexed across many keys -- namely all of the keys in the key groups assigned to that task slot. `initializeState` is just called once, and it needs to perform whatever actions are needed for all of those keys. (And there is no way to determine which keys are relevant to a given instance.)

The assumption is that the state backend is always available. The only time this isn't true is if the remote filesystem storing the snapshot is unavailable, in which case there's nothing you can do about it -- except for rebuilding the state from scratch. E.g., you could use the state processor API to build a new state snapshot from the data in the database.

Comment: Got it  . Is there a way to recover from the ES results data when the backend is not available?

Comment: What's the scenario you are trying to protect against?

Comment: In order to prevent unlimited state growth, I set ttl for state ( 5 days), When I process the data and cannot get it from the State, I have to query ES results data to see if the data is completely new or the state is out of date. Because there is very little data updated 5 days ago, I think the current solution is a bit bad .I don't know how to solve this

Comment: Initialize state is only called once, when Flink is booting up. Doing something then isn't going to help with your scenario. What you could do is to send records for which the state is missing through an async i/o operator that checks the DB.